# How to use glib on iphone?

Tags: iphone, glib

I'm working on a project these days. A third party library was included in my project, and the library is based on glib. That really make me crazy. Can you everybody tell me what should I do?

How to use glib on an iphone application? Dose apple allow us use glib for iphone application? and let me sell my application on app store?

Comment: I explain how you can do it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17733328/1856278

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it's certainly possible to compile and link glib for iOS, it seems that there's a legal problem: glib uses LGPL and [some think LGPL is not compatible with Apple's terms](http://loufranco.com/blog/files/lgpl-and-the-iphone.html).